# If your project is including several static libraries that include the same class, how can you elegantly get around a duplicate symbol error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

We are looking for an elegant solution to this dilemma that does NOT involve manually changing code to prefix it. This seems to generally be the only way people deal with that.

For example the NSData+Base64 category might be in two separate libraries. But if these two are added to one app there must be some sort of intelligent way to choose one version.

Is there a way to make symbols in a library (.a) unique so that the linker would only take one (preferable the never version) of a class that is contained in both libraries.

Comment: It's a bad library if they don't use prefixes. E.g. `NSData+IEFBase64`

Comment: I agree with @Ief2. The only real solution is prefixes and all libraries should prefix things. There's no other solution that doing that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no easy way like I was looking for. You can manually hack libraries and add a prefix. You can also use compatibility aliasing, but that works only with source code.